# How to troubleshoot: RODBC ERROR: state 08001, code 0,

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

Here is my connection string

```
library(RODBC)

odbconnection <- 
  odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQLServer;Server=some_address; Database=some_db;Uid=some_username; Pwd=some_password")
```

it returns:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQLServer;Server=some_address; Database=some_db;Uid=some_username; Pwd=some_password") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 0, message [RStudio][SqlServer] Problem establishing connection to the server.
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQLServer;Server=some_address; Database=some_db;Uid=some_username; Pwd=some_password") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

How can I troubleshoot this error: `[RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 0,`?

Comment: You could try `debug(ROBDBC::odbcDriverConnect)` before the command...

Comment: @Christoph well, it worked, but there is quite a bit to read. `DBI` library gave a bit more information, but still very obscure. It looks like it has something to with drivers or how they are installed on our linux machine

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `DBI` package and `host:port/service_name` such as

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(drv, 'user', 'pass', 'some_address:someport/some_db')
dbGetQuery(con,"select count(*) from some_db")
```